# Value initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

> **$8.5/7** states that
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>   is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>   called.

I am unable to appreciate the last part of this statement "if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called."

Can someone please explain this with an example?

```
class A
{
    int x;
};

class B : A {};

B b{};
```

I think `B` in the code above is having a non-trivial constructor. But how do I observe call to `B`'s implicitly declared constructor and make sure that my compiler is calling it?

Comment: Why do you think `B` has a non-trivial constructor? It meets all the conditions for a trivial constructor given in C++11 12.1/5.

Answer (score 6):

> I think B in the code above is having a non-trivial constructor.

In your example, the constructor is trivial.

Looking at the conditions in C++11 12.1/5, neither class has a user-declared constructor, virtual functions, virtual base classes, members with initialisers, or members of class type; `A` has no base classes and `B` only has a trivial base class.

> But how do I observe call to B's implicitly declared constructor and make sure that my compiler is calling it?

One way to make a class with an implicit, but non-trivial, default constructor is to have a non-trivial member or base class:

```
struct A {
    // A user-declared constructor is non-trivial
    A() {std::cout << "Construct A\n";}
};

struct B : A {};
```

Now you can (indirectly) observe the implicit constructor of `B` being called, by observing the side-effect when it calls the constructor of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation after N3797:

> A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.

Therefore, since you don't declare a default constructor for `B`, it is not user-provided.
The following then applies:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> — its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base
>   classes (10.1), and
>
> — no non-static data member of its class has a
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer*, and
>
> — all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default
>   constructors, and
>
> — for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class
>   type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
>   constructor.

So it is indeed trivial, since we can apply the same procedure recursively for `A`.

#### Other examples:

```
struct A { A() = default; }; // Trivial default constructor!
struct A { A() = delete; }; // Also trivial!
struct A { A(); }; // Can't be trivial!

struct B { virtual void f(); }
struct A : B {}; // Non-trivial default constructor.

struct B {};
struct A : virtual B {}; // Non-trivial default constructor.
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have this one

```
struct A {
  string a;
  int value;
};

int main() {
  A a = A();
  return a.value;
}
```

`a.value` is zero when we return that value, because the object was zero-initialized. But that is not enough, because `a` also contains a string member which has a constructor. For that constructor to be called, the standard arranges that `A`'s constructor is called, which will eventually lead to constructing the member.